# MYSQL / SQL Count Percentage Query

Tags: php, mysql, json

What I have

```
$query =
  "SELECT
      status_type,
      COUNT(*) as count,
      kpi_type,
      COUNT('kpi') * 100.00 as percentage
  FROM
      main
  GROUP BY
      status_type DESC;";
```

What I am getting.

```
[{"Status":"SOLD","KPI_Percentage":"1400","KPI":"SALE","Status_Count":"14"}]
```

Here is my JSON array

```
 $JSON_output[] = array('Status'         => $row['pin_status'],
                           'KPI'            => $row['kpi_type'],
                           'KPI_Percentage'         => $row['percent'],
                           'Status_Count'           => $row['count'],);}}
```

What I am trying to do...

```
[{"status":"value","kpi":"value","count":"12""percentage":"%32.42"}]
```

I am trying to count `status_type`, and show `status_type`, and I am trying to show `kpi_type`, and count % of `kpi_type` compared to other `kpi_type`s so If I have 3 sold, and 2 lead, and 5 prospects it would show: "LEAD: 20% SOLD 30% PROSPECTS 50%"

Table

```
+------+-----------------+------------------+--------------+
| ID   | kpi_type        | status_type      | Is Deleted   |
+------+-----------------+------------------+--------------+
|    1 |            SALE |SOLD              |     no       |
|    2 |            LEAD |Maybe             |     no       |
|    3 |            LEAD |Hot Lead          |     no       |
|    4 |        PROSPECT |Not Home          |     no       |
|    5 |            SALE |SOLD              |     no       |
|    6 |            LEAD |Maybe             |     no       |
|    7 |            LEAD |Hot Lead          |     no       |
|    8 |  Not Interested |Not Interested    |     no       |
+------+-----------------+------------------+--------------+
```

What answer I am seeking...

```
$query = //// THE CORRECT GOODS TO INSERT INTO THIS QUERY ////
  "SELECT
      status_type,
      COUNT(*) as count,
      kpi_type,
      COUNT('kpi') * 100.00 as percentage
  FROM
      main
  GROUP BY
      status_type DESC;";
```

Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: can you some records from your table..

Comment: Not sure what you mean?

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do?! Can you clarify this?

Comment: table is main / column is KPI_type, and Status_type

Comment: I am trying to count Status_type, and show status_type, and I am trying to show kpi_type, and count % of kpi_type compared to other kpi_types so If I have 3 sold, and 2 lead, and 5 prospects it would show LEAD: 20% SOLD 30% PROSPECTS 50%

Comment: Status would show various status. KPI type LEAD might call for 5 different status. where as KPI type SALE might only call for 2 other status's? Make sense?

Comment: Please share your table structure.

Comment: Added the table structure to OP.

Comment: `GROUP BY status DESC;";` ... Do you mean `GROUP BY status_type DESC;";` ? I don't see `status` in your table tructure

Comment: To reply to a comment always start off with `@username` This way the person you are replying to will be notified of your reply. We don't typically sit on one page waiting for a reply.

Comment: @raveenanigam updated OP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$query = "SELECT status_type, kpi_type, Count(*) as count,((Count(*)  * 100.0)/ (select Count(*) FROM main)) AS Percentage
                    FROM main
                    GROUP BY status_type, kpi_type
                    ORDER BY status_type, kpi_type";
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try the below query:

```
    SELECT status_type, kpi_type, Count(*), 
    ((Count(*)  * 100.0)/ (select Count(*) FROM main)) AS Percentage
    FROM main
    GROUP BY status_type, kpi_type
    ORDER BY status_type, kpi_type
```

added comment.

Comment: showing back as [{"Status":null,"KPI":"Lead","Percentage":null,"Count":null},

Comment: i tried with the same records and with same query. It's working fine

Comment: [{"pin_status":null,"KPI":"Lead","Percentage":"0.31596","Count":null},

Comment: "SELECT kpi_type, kpi_type, Count(*), 
        ((Count(*)  * 100.0)/ (select Count(*) FROM main_pins)) AS Percentage
        FROM main_pins
        GROUP BY pin_status, kpi_type
        ORDER BY pin_status, kpi_type";

Comment: I see where I added kpi_type twice. Should have added pin_status instead. now I am getting this [{"pin_status":"C - Net Only","KPI":"Lead","Percentage":"0.31596","Count":null} so not defining the count variable ?

Comment: Got it, i had to call Count(*) as Count

Answer (score 0):

I don't have MySql in front of me right now, but you need to get the total count of all records 
and then do a group by Status and KPI something like this (This is the rough syntax - maybe it'll get you closer):

```
select @Total:=Count(*) from InputTable;
select `Status`, `Kpi`, Count(*) as Status_Count, ((Count(*)  * 100.0)/ @Total) AS KPI_Percentage
from InputTable 
group by `Status`, `Kpi`
order by `Status`, `KPI`;
```

Results from query

```
        Invalid query: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual
     that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
     near 'select [status_type], [kpi_type], Count(), ((Count() * 100.0)/ @Total) 
    AS Perc' at line 3 Whole query: select @Total =(select Count() from main_pins) 
    select [status_type], [kpi_type], Count(), ((Count(*) * 100.0)/ @Total) 
    AS Percentage from main_pins group by [status_type], [kpi_type] order by [status_type],
 [kpi_type]
```

Comment: Invalid query: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'select [status_type], [kpi_type], Count(*), ((Count(*) * 100.0)/ @Total) AS Perc' at line 3 Whole query: select @Total =(select Count(*) from main_pins) select [status_type], [kpi_type], Count(*), ((Count(*) * 100.0)/ @Total) AS Percentage from main_pins group by [status_type], [kpi_type] order by [status_type], [kpi_type]

Answer (score 0):

Was able to get the answer after tinkering with Raveenanigam's answer. Thanks everyone for the help and the upvotes to get some attention.

```
$query = "SELECT status_type, kpi_type, Count(*) as count,((Count(*)  * 100.0)/ (select Count(*) FROM main)) AS Percentage
                    FROM main
                    GROUP BY status_type, kpi_type
                    ORDER BY status_type, kpi_type";
```

result given.

```
[{"status_type":"Hot Lead","KPI":"Lead","Percentage":"0.31596","Count":"2"}
```